# Highcharts error in a community

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, highcharts

I have made a lightning component which includes a chart rendered by Highcharts.

This component works when previewing the app. However, when the component is placed on a employee community page using the community builder, I get

> Highcharts Error #13 (Rendering div not found)

on page load.

Has anyone experienced similar, or know why this is happening?

Div in component:

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/Highcharts506/code/highcharts.js" afterScriptsLoaded='{!c.onHighchartsLoaded}'/>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
```

The `onHighchartsLoaded` method calls the Highcharts rendering:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {...});
```

Comment: Please add the code snippets to assist you further

Comment: Add a little bit, but not exactly sure what could be helpful - the code is a very basic use case of Highcharts

Comment: Would like to see component markup and the JavaScript controller code

Comment: The two lines shown are effectively the component markup and controller code for the chart as far as I understand

Comment: How do you import the high chart library ? Ltng:require

Answer (score 2):

As Doug Chasman answered on this question [this link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155236/lightning-component-scripts-loading-issues-since-spring-17-update/155264#155264) there is an issue with static resources in Spring'17. The issue is being tracked in R&D by W-3615844

Except this, are you that you're targeting the div correctly when calling Highcharts ? Maybe try with a component.find or document.getElementById ?