# SVG Icons not displaying in Spring '17 pre-release environment

Tags: lightning-aura-components, bug, svg-icon, spring17

I'm seeing SVG icons not rendering in a Spring '17 environment. I'm using custom SVG lightning component from [SLDS framework](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/). The icons in my component continue to display correctly in existing Winter 17 environment of platform, but when I test in Spring '17 all of the icons are not displayed.

When I checked icon path in browser console, i noticed all of the icons are having incorrect Path URL in the SVG URL elements. And I'm using documented way to set SVG Url:

```
{!$Resource.mynmsp__SLDS0202 + '/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search'}
```

The above SVG URL is evaluated correctly as:

```
/resource/1470228498000/mynmsp__SLDS0202/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search
```

But in Spring '17 pre-release orgs I'm seeing lots of Console Errors like this:
Unsafe attempt to load URL

> https://vc-prerelease-dev-ed--advpm.gus.visual.force.com/resource/1470228498000/mynmsp__SLDS0202/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#search
>   from frame with URL
>   https://vc-prerelease-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/one.app#/n/mynmsp__My_Lightning_App?t=1484050965092.
>   Domains, protocols and ports must match.

UPDATE: 
I'm experiencing similar issue in the Utility Bar, when I drop my custom lightning component into it. No svg icons are loaded, citing similar error message in browser console window (mentioned above).

Comment: I'm encountering this same issue in one of the orgs. In another org, the svg is displayed with larger padding on the right. Both on them are on spring 17. The symbols.svg is loaded sometimes and sometimes it is not loaded.

Comment: I'm experiecing similar issue in the Utility Bar, when I drop my custom lightning component into it. No svg icons are loaded, citing similar error in console window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Doug Chasman answered [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155236/lightning-component-scripts-loading-issues-since-spring-17-update), there is currently a global issue with static resources in Spring '17. 
I guess you can create a case if you want to know more about when the fix is gonna be live.

Comment: I found the Known Issue for the internal issue number provided from this thread from Doug. Thanks. For general sharing and status tracking for all, this is the issue link - https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000ers4QAA

Answer (score 1):

While this does not directly address your issue, it sidesteps it quite well:

Stop using custom `SVG` components - you don't need them anymore. Instead use the built in ones. Your icon can be replaced by this:

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:search" size="x-small" class="slds-icon slds-icon--selected slds-icon--x-small slds-icon-text-default " />
```

The are three main attributes here - `utility:search` is the actual icon, while the `size` and `class` attributes can be worked out from the slds website. You should be able to copy the class from your `SVG` component directly to this component.

Make sure you set the `size` attribute to the same as specified in the `class` - in this case `x-small`.

Comment: Thanks @Caspar, though I do know the base components, my lightning components (which have more than 1 currently) have compatibility issues with base components. Moreover couple of components I have built refer custom svg map from static resources and those cannot be referenced in base Icon component. And it is comprehensive task to update all my code to use base components instead of static resource ones :-), though wherever possible I'm now using base components, but even if one image cannot be rendered make the component unusable for end users, that's my worry :-)