# Spring 17 - Lightning fails to load Static Resources with $Resource in Chrome,Firefox and Edge

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, static-resources, winter17

After updating from winter 17 to spring 17 I am facing random issues with `$Resource` variable. This issue is observed:

- Chrome
- Firefox
- Edge

and to my surprise everything works smoothly in IE11.

**Issue Description:**

- I am using `$Resource` variable extensively to reference the resource prefix in stylesheet, script and image tags
- Till Winter 17 everything works fine, but after upgrade it randomly started throwing 404 resource not found exception
- When dived deeper it looks like `"{!$Resource.zip_file}/Images/test.png"` was resolved to `"/Images/test.png"` instead of `"/resource/zip_file/Images/test.png"`

**Source:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <div>
        With $Resource: <br/>
        <img src="{!$Resource.prmsf__Pramata+'/Images/powered-by-pramata-logo.png'}" width="300"/>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div>
        With /resource: <br/>
        <img src="/resource/prmsf__Pramata/Images/powered-by-pramata-logo.png" width="300"/>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**In Winter 17:**

[image]

**In Spring 17:**

[image]

**Note:**

- This is observed consistently when the **Cache Buster** is enabled in chrome
- Currently I modified the code to `/resource` instead of `$Resource` but I am curious to know long term fix since documentation doesn't support the former

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug... I guess that's another one we need to report...

Comment: the known issues list with spring 17 is growing..

Comment: For all the fuss made about unit tests in Apex and the 'hammer', you'd think it'd be part of Lightning by now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Doug Chasman answered on [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/155236/lightning-component-scripts-loading-issues-since-spring-17-update/155264#155264) there is an issue with static resources in Spring'17. The issue is being tracked in R&D by W-3615844